# How can I trigger a child component function only for some specific parents component in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I had a component say `child.jsx` and it has a button in it which triggers a function (named: `handleClick`) defined in the same component on clicking the button.

Now I imported this in two components say `parent1.jsx` and `parent2.jsx`.

What I want now is to call the `handleClick` function only when the button is clicked under `parent1.jsx` component and not in `parent2.jsx`.

Anyone can help with efficient solution to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a props like EnabledButton from `parent1.jsx` and check that into your `click handler` function

**This is your Child Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Child(props) {

  function onclickHandler(event) {
    if(props.EnableButton)
    {    
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Click Here"
        name="button"
        onClick={onclickHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

**How you pass props from `parent1.jsx` into your Child Component**

```
<Child EnableButton ={true}>
```

**How you pass props from `parent2.jsx` into your Child Component**

```
<Child EnableButton ={false}>
```

> Using this concept you can hide that button too.